# Creating EDITABLE hotspot image?

Tags: 2010

## Background:

Interesting issue for SharePoint power users:

I embedded an image into our SharePoint site and added some hotspots (hotspots are clickable hyperlinks assigned to different areas of an image).

[image]

## The Problem:

I'd like to edit the text that's part of the the image. For example, a hexagon that is labeled "Training" I might want to rename "Costs". Or, my bigger problem - what if I want to add another hexagon to the image?

There doesn't seem a way to easily add text to an image in SharePoint.

Of course, I could make the changes in Word, re-upload the edited image and redraw the hotspots, but this would be a total time waster.

## Questions:

Is there any way around this? I should mention that my image is a screenshot of some (Microsoft) Word SmartArt. Is there a way to embed this piece of word art instead? Or perhaps somehow add EDITABLE text on top of each hexagon hotspot?

I'm using SharePoint 2010. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use SharePoint Designer. Very straightforward. Open the page holding image, click into image, and Picture Format with Hotspot option pops up. Make sure to Save and then exit Designer.

Comment: Did you read my question? I'm already using hotspots. The issue is being able to edit the image itself without reuploading.